# Loop through validation list and print pdf to a folder defined by a cell

Tags: list, validation, pdf, printing, filepath

I used an answer from a similar question to get the vba below. This vba script works when the folderpath is hardcoded but I am hoping to have the folder for the printed pdf file be definde by a cell ("G7").

```
Sub Loop_Through_List()
    
    Sheets("Report Template").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
    Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range
    Dim folderPath            As String

    folderPath = GetFolder(Range("G7").Value)
    'folderPath = GetFolder()

    Set DV_Cell = Range("B5")

    Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
        PDFActiveSheet folderPath
    Next
    
    Sheets("Notes").Select
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub PDFActiveSheet(Optional ByVal folderPath As String = "")
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim myFile                As Variant
    Dim strFile               As String
    Dim sFolder               As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'enter name and select folder for file
    ' start in current workbook folder
    strFile = ws.Range("B5").Value

    If folderPath = "" Then
        '--- if no folder path is specified, then default to
        '    the same path as the active workbook
        folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        If Len(folderPath) = 0 Then
            '--- to force Excel to have a path (instead of no
            '    path at all), use the current directory
            '    notation
            folderPath = "."
        End If
    End If
    myFile = folderPath & "\" & strFile

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
            From:=1, _
            To:=2

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim dlg                   As FileDialog
    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    dlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    dlg.Title = "Select folder to save PDFs"
    If dlg.Show = -1 Then
        GetFolder = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the folder name is already in cell G7, you don't need the GetFolder function:

Current code

```
folderPath = GetFolder(Range("G7").Value)
```

Replace with:

```
folderPath = Range("G7").Value
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit and response. The error handler returns "Could not create PDF file" when I replace with folderPath = Range("G7").Value

Comment: What is the folder path in G7?    Is it valid with the correct permissions?

Comment: The folder path is "C:\Users\GevorkJ\Documents\Toxicology Program\Query\Routine\Template
". Yes, I believe it is valid with correct permissions. The script works appropriately if I hardcode the folderpath as quoted.

Comment: I see a space after Template. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. My apologies. There is no space in the cell, it reads "C:\Users\GevorkJ\Documents\Toxicology Program\Query\Routine\Template"

Comment: Curious. After you set myFile, call `MsgBox myFile` to check the full file name

Comment: Oh, interesting. I added "Call MsgBox(myFile)" after I set myFile and the msg box states the location as B5 instead of G7. I am not sure where the reference is messing up.

Comment: Correction, it doesn't seem to be identifying the path in G7. I added a Call MsgBox(folderpath) after folderpath = Range("G7").Value and the msg box returns blank. Also, the Call MsgBox(myFile) returns "\"&"B5" instead of "G7"&"\"&"B5".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with Mike's help. In the end, I used ActiveWorkbook.Path & "" to define the folderpath. I don't know if any of the code is redundant but it works for what I need. Thank you very much.

```
Sub Loop_Through_List()
    
    Sheets("Report Template").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
    Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range
    Dim folderPath            As String
    Dim Path            As String

    folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    'folderPath = GetFolder()

    Set DV_Cell = Range("B5")

    Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
        PDFActiveSheet folderPath
    Next
    
    Sheets("Notes").Select
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub PDFActiveSheet(Optional ByVal folderPath As String = "")
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim myFile                As Variant
    Dim strFile               As String
    Dim sFolder               As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'enter name and select folder for file
    ' start in current workbook folder
    strFile = ws.Range("B5").Value

    If folderPath = "" Then
        '--- if no folder path is specified, then default to
        '    the same path as the active workbook
        folderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        If Len(folderPath) = 0 Then
            '--- to force Excel to have a path (instead of no
            '    path at all), use the current directory
            '    notation
            folderPath = "."
        End If
    End If
    myFile = folderPath & "\" & strFile
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
            From:=1, _
            To:=2

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim dlg                   As FileDialog
    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    dlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    dlg.Title = "Select folder to save PDFs"
    If dlg.Show = -1 Then
        GetFolder = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Function
```